# Animating multiple views with one onClick()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, android-imageview

In my Android app, I have some custom views that I made (as an extension of `AppCompatImageView`) which have an `onClick` method within the class that performs some animation.

When the view is tapped, it moves to a certain point of the screen. However, if there's already a view there (one that has been tapped previously) I need that to move out of the way. How do I get a tap on one view to call a method (it can be the same method, and the views will be of the same class) for both the tapped button and whichever (if any) view is already 'docked' in this position.

The classes have this `onClick` method that works fine:

```
public class CustomView extends AppCompatImageView implements View.OnClickListener {

    private boolean docked;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        if (docked)
            //Perform some action
        else
            //Perform another action
    }
}
```

The views are all of this same class, and are created at run-time in the main activity and then added to the layout.

Can anyone suggest the best way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the view that has already tapped then call this method `performClick()` on that view to call its `onClick()` method. So both view's (Currently clicked and previously clicked) `onClick()` method will call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). Send broadcast when tapped on the view which is received by other views to move. Write that BroadcastReceiver class in the same class.